# Where can normal weight come from other than extrinsics?

Tags: extrinsic, weight

I have noticed on Moonbeam that the `Normal system.blockWeight` is often much higher than the sum of Normal class extrinsics included in the block. Example:

https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fwss.api.moonbeam.network#/explorer/query/0x438d0a0323d6434a5426ec02dfbfe1847cbfafcf05517c1515029428e5f5b85d

(block 1813141 / 0x438d0a0323d6434a5426ec02dfbfe1847cbfafcf05517c1515029428e5f5b85d)

This block includes some `ethereum.transact` transactions totaling `14_967_850_000` Normal weight, but the `system.blockWeight` Normal class for the same block is `221_040_085_000`.

It is common for these to be different, although the two numbers are sometimes identical as well. Sometimes they are both 0 for a block.

Where could this discrepancy be coming from?

EDIT: This question led to both this issue: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/12252 and this fix: https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/pull/851

Comment: Good catch! Something is def. wrong here. The `ExtrinsicBaseWeight` is missing as well in PolkadotJS.

Comment: Yea fees work, but look at how much weight PolkadotJS reports for a `System.Remark`. I can bring that down to zero, def. not enough.

Comment: Thanks, @OliverTale-Yazdi. The main issue turned out to be a bug in frontier where weight was not refunded in post-dispatch (link in my edit above), but it looks like your issue is also relevant. Thanks for digging in!

Answer (score 2):

The total weight of the block comes from the sum of:

1. work done in `on_initialize`, which is done *before* extrinsics
2. work done in extrinsics
3. work done in `on_finalize`, which is done *after* extrinsics

Doing heavy work in `on_finalize` is discouraged, because the block may already be filled with extrinsics. In fact, the `on_initialize` function of pallets is supposed to estimate the weight of both `on_initialize` and `on_finalize` in order to prevent the block from being filled with too many extrinsics.

Comment: Thanks, @rob, but this was asking about `Normal` weight and a discrepancy seen in the accounting for it.